# Continuously embedded subspace (with own topolog. structure) of a separable real Hilbert space is itself separable

Tags: hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

Let $H$ be a separable real Hilbert space and let $V$ be another real Hilbert space. Additionally, $V$ is a dense subspace of $H$ and is continuously embedded, i. e.
$$ \exists C>0: \forall v\in V: \left\| v \right\|_H \leq C \cdot \left\| v \right\|_V. $$
Note, that $V$ has its own scalar product and has therefore a different topological structure.

Is V a separable space w. r. t. $\left\| . \right\|_V$?
If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: Nice question.  We may (on the side) note that the "inclusion" of $L^\infty[0,1]$ into $L^2[0,1]$ continuously densely embeds a non-separable Banach space into a separable one.  So your question is whether that can happen with a Hilbert space.

Comment: Here is another common example, that illustrates that the answer is 'no' for Banach-spaces: $C^{0,\alpha}[0,1]\subset C^1[0,1]$ (where the left space contains $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous functions and is non-separable, as shown e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564139/is-the-space-c-alpha-separable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, let $V$ be a nonseparable Hilbert space, and let $T : V \to H$ be linear, injective, and $\|T(v)\|_H \le C\|v\|_V$.  That is, $T$ is a bounded linear operator.  We must show this is impossible.

Let $T^* : H \to V$ be the adjoint operator.  Since $T$ is injective, we know that
$T^*$ has dense range.

> Suppose $T^*(H)$ is not dense in $V$.  There is $v \in V$ with $v \ne 0$ and $v \perp T^*(H)$.  For every $h \in H$,$$0 = \langle v,T^*h\rangle_V = \langle Tv,h\rangle_H$$  Thus $Tv=0$.  So $T$ is not injective.

Now $T^*(H)$ is a continuous image of a separable set, so $T^*(H)$ is itself separable.  But it is dense in $V$, so $V$ is separable.

Comment: I think this argument also works for Banach spaces if $H^*$ is separable and $V$ is reflexive.

Comment: @GEdgar Why does it have to be that $v \perp T^*(H)$? And why is the continuous image of a separable set itself separable?

Comment: If $f : A \to B$ is continuous, and $D \subseteq A$ is dense in $A$, then $f(D)$ is dense in $f(B)$.  If $D$ is countable, then $f(D)$ is countable.

Comment: In Hilbert space, any closed linear subspace $E$ that is not the whole space has nonzero orthogonal complement $E^\perp$.  This is the kernel of the orthogonal projection onto $E$.